# In install4j configurable form, is it possible to enable a disabled Next button as soon as some value is entered in a text field?

Tags: install4j

In the configurable form I'm able to disable the Next button of the current form, using pre-activation script pesent in Screen Activation of it's properties by using

```
context.getWizardContext().setNextButtonEnabled(false);
```

But I need to enable it as soon as the user enters some value in the username and password text field. I have tried enabling it by calling this method

```
context.getWizardContext().setNextButtonEnabled(true);
```

from User Input->Validation Expression of the corresponding text field. But eventhough I am not able to acheive, what I wanted. Is there any possiblity of doing this in install4j ?

This is code that I have entered in validation Expression :

```
String username = context.getVariable("userName").toString().trim();
String password = context.getVariable("password").toString().trim();
if((username.equals(null)) || (username.isEmpty())) {
context.getWizardContext().setNextButtonEnabled(false);
}
else if((password.equals(null)) || (password.isEmpty())) {
context.getWizardContext().setNextButtonEnabled(false);
}
else {
context.getWizardContext().setNextButtonEnabled(true); 
}
return true;
```

I hope this code will not execute since I entered in the Validation Expression. But at which place the code have to be inserted so that as soon as user enters some value in username and password field, the Next button of this form will get enabled ?

Comment: While the user is still entering some value in the password text field. In the "Key validation expression" property if I try to get the entered value of the current field i.e still user haven't completed entering in the password field by using String password = context.getVariable("password").toString().trim(); Now in password field whether I will get until what user have entered or null(this happens only if you save to the context object only after getting the focus away from text box) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validation expression of the screen is only executed when the user clicks on the "Next" button. The "Text field" form component has two additional scripts that are executed earlier:

- "Key validation expression" property -> Invoked after a single key is pressed
- "Input validation expression" property -> Invoked when the text field loses focus

Comment: Thanks for the reply...And Eventhough after entering the above code in "Key validation expression" property I'm not able to enable the disabled Next button !

Comment: While the user is still entering some value in the password text field. In the "Key validation expression" property if I try to get the entered value of the current field i.e still user haven't completed entering in the password field by using String password = context.getVariable("password").toString().trim(); Now in password field whether I will get until what user have entered or null(this happens only if you save to the context object only after getting the focus away from text box) ?

Comment: Variables are saved when the user clicks on "Next". If you want to save them earlier, call `formEnvironment.saveFormComponents()` in a script. In the "Key validation expression" the text of the text field component is available through the "text" variable.

Comment: @ Ingo Kegel Thanks for the info... Finally I have made it with your valuable inputs.